How can I make my Jest test recognize jsx/tsx syntax?
My test is refusing to recognize < angle brackets.
    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

    Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

    By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.

    Here's what you can do:
     • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
     • If you are trying to use TypeScript, see https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-typescript
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
    For information about custom transformations, see:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation

    Details:

    /Users/myname/projects/rn/tictactoe/__tests__/QuestionBoard.test.tsx:27
        const { getByText } = (0, react_native_1.render)(<QuestionBoard_1.default questions={questions} onSubmit={jest.fn()}/>);
                                                         ^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1505:14)

here is my eslintrc.js
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  extends: '@react-native',
  overrides: [
    {
      // Test files only
      files: ['**/__tests__/**/*.[jt]s?(x)', '**/?(*.)+(spec|test).[jt]s?(x)'],
      extends: ['plugin:@testing-library/react-native',],
    },
  ],
};

here is my babel.config.js
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: ['@babel/plugin-transform-runtime'],
};

here is my jest.config.js
module.exports = {
  preset: 'react-native',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.js'],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.jsx?$': 'babel-jest',
    '^.+\\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest',
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    'node_modules/(?!(react-native|@react-native|@testing-library/react-native|@aws-amplify|uuid)/)',
  ],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '\\.(css|less)$': 'identity-obj-proxy',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  },
};

here is my jest.setup.js
import '@testing-library/jest-native/extend-expect';

here is my tsconfig.json
{
  "extends": "@react-native/typescript-config/tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["jest", "@testing-library/jest-native"],
    "skipLibCheck": true
}
}

here is my package.json
{
  "name": "tictactoe",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-amplify/api": "^6.1.8",
    "@aws-amplify/auth": "^6.8.3",
    "@aws-amplify/cli": "^12.13.1",
    "@aws-amplify/react-native": "^1.1.6",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^2.1.0",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^11.4.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^7.0.14",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^7.1.0",
    "aws-amplify": "^6.10.3",
    "expo": "^52.0.18",
    "global": "^4.4.0",
    "react": "18.3.1",
    "react-native": "^0.76.5",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.21.2",
    "react-native-get-random-values": "^1.11.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^3.16.5",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^5.0.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^4.3.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.2.0",
    "uuid": "^11.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.26.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.25.9",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.26.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.26.3",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.25.0",
    "@react-native-community/cli": "15.0.1",
    "@react-native-community/cli-platform-android": "^15.1.3",
    "@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios": "^15.1.3",
    "@react-native/babel-preset": "0.76.5",
    "@react-native/eslint-config": "0.76.5",
    "@react-native/metro-config": "0.76.5",
    "@react-native/typescript-config": "0.76.5",
    "@testing-library/jest-native": "^5.4.3",
    "@testing-library/react-native": "^12.9.0",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.14",
    "@types/react": "^19.0.2",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^19.0.0",
    "@types/uuid": "^10.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.7.0",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.77.0",
    "prettier": "2.8.8",
    "react-test-renderer": "^19.0.0",
    "ts-jest": "^29.2.5",
    "typescript": "5.0.4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=18"
  },
  "packageManager": "yarn@1.22.22"
}

here is my component
import { Pressable, ScrollView, Text, TextInput, View } from 'react-native';
import * as React from 'react';

type QuestionsBoardProps = {
  questions: string[];
  onSubmit: (obj: {}) => void;
};

function QuestionsBoard({ questions, onSubmit }: QuestionsBoardProps) {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState({});

  return (
    <ScrollView>
      {questions.map((q, index) => (
        <View key={q}>
          <Text>{q}</Text>
          <TextInput
            accessibilityLabel="answer input"
            accessibilityHint="input"
            onChangeText={(text) =>
              setData((state) => ({
                ...state,
                [index + 1]: { q, a: text },
              }))
            }
          />
        </View>
      ))}
      <Pressable accessibilityRole="button" onPress={() => onSubmit(data)}>
        <Text>Submit</Text>
      </Pressable>
    </ScrollView>
  );
}

export default QuestionsBoard;


and here is the test
import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react-native';
import QuestionBoard from '../QuestionBoard';

test('renders QuestionsBoard component', () => {
  const questions = ['q1', 'q2'];
  const { getByText } = render(
    <QuestionBoard questions={questions} onSubmit={jest.fn()} />
  );

  expect(getByText('q1')).toBeTruthy();
  expect(getByText('q2')).toBeTruthy();
});



note, the test and the component test fine in an example project.
